# Cabal error for llvm-general

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc, cabal

Trying to install llvm-general-3.3.5.

Have a local ghc-7.6.3 installation so used the following command to configure the llvm-general package after downloading the binary:

```
runhaskell Setup configure --user --/path/to/local --with-compiler=7.6.3
```

as is suggested in the haskell.org pages [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package).
That gets this error:

```
Setup.hs:42:13:
Couldn't match expected type `ProgramSearchPath
                              -> IO (Maybe FilePath)'
            with actual type `IO (Maybe FilePath)'
In the return type of a call of `findJustBy'
Probable cause: `findJustBy' is applied to too many arguments
In the expression:
  findJustBy (findProgramLocation v) llvmConfigNames
In the expression:
  \ v -> findJustBy (findProgramLocation v) llvmConfigNames
```

Removing the configure options gets the same result. 
Any ideas? 
I'm on a Scientific linux machine.

Thank you!